# Backup/Restore List Views

Tags: 2010, list-view, backup, restore

I have a staging SharePoint 2010 environment which I have created quite a few List Views.

I would like to move these Views to my production server. I could not find any way to do it via backup and restore mechanism.

Is it possible to do this exercise? if so, could you please let me know how?

Thanks